# Join rows using C# Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, datatable

If there is a DataTable called STUDENTS

```
SubjectID       StudentName
----------      -------------
1               Mary
1               John
1               Sam
2               Alaina
2               Edward
```

How can we get the below DataTable as a result using Linq:

```
SubjectID       StudentName
----------      -------------
1               Mary, John, Sam
2               Alaina, Edward
```

I tried achieving this result using the foreach loop crawling through each datarow one by one but came across major performance hit.

Not good with Linq but trying my hands on it. I would post my answer once I get something concrete but any help would be appreciated in between.

Sample working code without using Linq but not giving the desired performance. The below foreach loop is taking around 15mins if the DataTable dt2 has around 3500 records.

```
        DataTable dtFiles = dt2.Clone();

        //Logic to filter out the files by keyword name filter.
        foreach (DataRow row in dt2.Rows)
        {
            string studentid = row.Field<string>("StudentID");
            string filter = "StudentID = '" + studentid + "'";
            if(dtFiles.Select(filter).Count() == 0)//this means keyword is new 
            {
                DataRow dr = dtFiles.NewRow();
                dr["StudentName"] = row["StudentName"];
                dr["StudentID"] = row["StudentID"];
                dtFiles.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            else
            {
                dtFiles.Select(filter).First<DataRow>()["StudentName"] += "," + row.Field<string>("StudentName");//Rows[0]
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't see how Linq is going to be any faster than a single pass through the collection. How many records are you talking about here? What are you trying to do?

Comment: The datatable has around 3500 records and it's taking around 10 - 15 mins to get it done. I'll try posting the sample code asap.

Comment: Any particular reason you want the result as a `DataTable`? You can easily get this as a list of a custom type... note that if you're fetching all the data into a `DataTable` to start with, that's *not* using LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: 3500 records should take only a few seconds to process - something is not right :| I believe the problem is using `dtFiles.Select..` - could it be turning the loop into O(n^2) or worse? - instead of a Hash-based look-up/probe. (I don't know what support DataTables have for indexing.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet : The point here is that I am fetching the data from an excel in the DataTable using OledbReader. Now I want that data to be in a particular format as specified above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get grouped data

```
var subjects = 
    from r in dtFiles.AsEnumerable()
    group r by r.Field<int>("SubjectID") into g
    select new {
       ID = g.Key,
       Students = String.Join(", ", g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("StudentName"))
    };
```

Then build DataTable (if you need it)

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("SubjectID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("StudentName", typeof(string));
// or you can just clone existing DataTable:
DataTable dt = dtFiles.Clone();

foreach(var subject in subjects)
   dt.Add(subject.ID, subject.Students);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little bit of a variation of the previous solution:

```
DataTable dt = dtFiles.Clone();

(from r in dtFiles.AsEnumerable()
         group r by r.Field<int>("SubjectID") into g
         select g)
         .Aggregate(dt, (d, g) =>
         {
              dt.Rows.Add(g.Key, String.Join(", ", g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("StudentName"))));
              return dt;
         });
```

Your result will be in the cloned DataTable dt.